# Can the Assuming function be used with ContourPlot or DensityPlot?

Tags: plotting, assumptions

I'm new to Mathematica, and for most purposes the program has served me well and been straightforward. However, I'm hitting a snag while trying to create a contour plot for the distribution function

$\qquad f(x,y) = (x\,y)^{p-1}/(\alpha + \beta\,x + \gamma\,y + \delta\,x\,y)^{p + q}$

Notice $x,y$ are variables, and $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta, p,$ and $q$ are constants. I need to set a list of assumptions for constants in the function, but my attempts have been fruitless. Every command yields a graph without an image.

I first tried assigning my function with its assumptions by:

```
Assuming[
  {x > 0, y > 0, p > 0, α > 0, β > 0, γ > 0, δ > 0}, 
  f[x_, y_] := 
    (x*y)^(p - 1)/(α + β*x + γ*y + δ*x*y)^(p + q)]
```

After the assignment, I tried plotting with `ContourPlot` and `DensityPlot`.

I'll provide just the `ContourPlot` expression below because not much changes across them:

```
ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, 0, 200}, {y, 0, 200}]
```

In regards to the `ContourPlot` code, I've changed the domain to both larger and smaller numbers to no avail. Neither `ContourPlot` nor `DensityPlot` provides an image. I then try the code without assigning the function beforehand, while including ContourPlot within the Assuming command:

```
Assuming[
  {α > 0, β > 0, γ > 0, δ > 0, p > 0}, 
  ContourPlot[(x*y)^(p - 1)/(α + β*x + γ*y + δ*x*y)^(p + q), {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}]]
```

I know this equation should produce some sort of image since it's simply a type of truncated distribution function. I believe I've narrowed down the issue to one of the following: Mathematica does not allow assumptions to be used with `ContourPlot/DensityPlot`, the distribution function is too complicated for Mathematica, or my user error is hindering me. My next step is to try creating different plots on the same graph for various pre-determined values of the parameters.

Any help is much appreciated. As previously mentioned, I'm not very experienced with Mathematica, so I'm more than willing to learn something new or help further explain my goals.

Comment: `MemberQ[Keys[Options[ContourPlot]], Assumptions]` returns `False`, so you can't use assumptions on `ContourPlot[]`. Your more pressing problem is that you have neglected to provide *concrete values* for your parameters, so there really is nothing for the plotter to do. (Also, `xy` and `x y` are very different things, which contributes to why you can't plot.)

Comment: That makes sense. I'll stop trying to use `Assumptions` with `ContourPlot` now. I don't know how I didn't catch myself sooner, but I now realize I had typed `xy` instead of `x*y`. This actually fixes another, unrelated issue I was having with the code. That said, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Shouldn't `(xy)^(p - 1)/(α + βx + γy + δxy)^(p + q)]` be `(x y)^(p - 1)/(α + β x + γ y + δ x y)^(p + q)]` The additional spaces make a big difference.

Comment: Yes, was thinking the same thing, otherwise Mathematica thinks each term is one variable for example `xy` and not the product of these.

Comment: You also need to set the constants to some values to plot your function.  To take a simpler example, to plot `Exp[-x^2 / (2 sigma^2)] / (sigma Sqrt[2 pi]`, you would need to specify `sigma`.

Comment: I just updated the original post to show multiplication!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As has been said in the comments to your question, because all plotting functions are based on strictly numerical calculations, you must give definite values to all six parameters. If you are in the position where you have no good idea how the function behaves as the parameters vary, you can explore the situation with `Manipulate`. Here is an example.

```
f[α_, β_, γ_, δ_, p_, q_][x_, y_] := (x y)^(p - 1)/(α + β x + γ y + δ x y)^(p + q)

With[{ϵ = .0001},
  Manipulate[
    ContourPlot[f[α, β, γ, δ, p, q][x, y], {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}],
    {α, ϵ, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
    {β, ϵ, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
    {γ, ϵ, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
    {δ, ϵ, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
    {p, 1, 4, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
    {q, 1, 4, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]]
```

[image: demo]

Note: I have no clue about what comprise good ranges for either the parameters or the variables. I made some simple assumptions about them. You should revise these assumptions to suit your needs.

Comment: It looks like you separated out the "constants" and the "variables" in your function definition.  Is there any significance to that other than convenience of notation?  Where is this documented (just did a quick search for defining functions and did not see it)?  Thanks!

Comment: @mjw, [this tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ExpressionsWithHeadsThatAreNotSymbols.html) might be of interest. It is not necessary to separate parameters and variables in this way, but it is definitely convenient.

Comment: @mjw. It is documented as J.M. points out. A higher level reference which a list of links about topics concerning functions is [this one](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionalOperationsOverview.html), which included the link given by J.M.

Comment: @mjw. I use this style more for reasons of clarity than convenience.

Comment: @J.M. Thank you!  So what is `f[a_,b_][x_,y_]`, a function?  Or a function of a function?  I guess that I understand that now the **head** of the expression is f[a,b].

Comment: @m_goldberg, yes, it does look neat.  But is there no difference practically?  According to the link J.M. gave, it looks to be a different construct.

Comment: @mjw, I've previously referred to it as an "expression with a compound head", but I am not aware of more standard terminology.

Comment: @mjw. `f[a_,b_][x_,y_]` is a pattern, nothing more. It is a pattern that can sometimes be useful (as in the case at hand) in making function definitions with `SetDelayed` or `Set`.

Comment: I feel like this is exactly what I needed since it allows for easy manipulation of the parameters. I'll have to play with this approach a little later in the day to see how it works. Maybe as a small pet project sometime later, I'll try to see if I can recreate something similar with ProbabilityDistribution, since this is a distribution function; but I don't know. This is pretty hard to beat!

Comment: @BanksOsborne, I'm glad you find my answer useful. Please consider accepting it. You can do that by clicking on the check mark that appears on the left of the answer below the down arrow.

Comment: @m_goldberg, will do!

Answer (score 0):

One way is to simply set the **constants** as variables in your function definition, and then set them to the values you want when you call the function:

```
f[x_, y_, α_, β_, γ_, δ_, p_, q_] := (x y)^(p -1)/(α + β x + γ y + δ x y)^(p + q);

ContourPlot[f[x, y, 2, 3, 4, 5, .5, .5], {x, 0, 200}, {y, 0, 200}]
```

[image]